# How to create a Number of arrays using a for loop? c#

Tags: c#

How to create number of arrays that has different names using a for loop?

```
for (c = 0; c <= 10; c++)
{ 
    string[] array = new string[5];
}
```

I can't use `array[c]` because it gives an error.

Also I want to identify those arrays uniquely.
How to do that?

Comment: Please, elaborate more your question

Comment: If you make a `string[][]`, you can identify each array uniquely.

Comment: Have you considered an array of arrays?

Comment: i want a array list like array1,array2,array3 ...... so for that if i change the code like array[c] it gives a error

Comment: mahee, lets say you did manage to do that, how would you then use `array9`? how would you know that variable exists? you need to make an array of arrays or better describe what problem you are trying to solve by doing this

Comment: @Dennis_E can you pleas give an example for that ?

Comment: i want to  take some list box contents to an array and split the letters of that contents and put those letters to arrays                                                      like if may first content is ONE  i want it in a array  [o][N][E]   .                       if second content is two  .....[T][W][O]  @Sayse

Comment: Variable name is a compile-time thing. Code (as your `for` loop and values assigned to `c`) are a run-time thing. Do you see the mismatch? If you want to _name_ arrays did you consider to use a **dictionary** (`Dictionary<string, string[]>`) instead? If index is enough even `string[][]` is good.

Comment: @mahee `string[][] array = new string[10][];` Then, inside the for-loop: `array[c] = new string[5];`

Answer (score -1):

First off, you need to declare `c` as a variable, unless you do so elsewhere in your code. `for (int c = 0; c <= 10; c++)`. After that, it creates the arrays of size `c` fine. As for identifying these arrays uniquely, that depends on what you're trying to do. You could always put all of the string array in an array of arrays. That gives you a way to uniquely identify each one.